# Custom build system for QML in Sublime Text 3

Tags: qml, sublimetext, sublimetext3, build-system

I have created a build system for QML in sublime, so selecting that build system and doing a ctrl+B builds the qml code for me. But every time I switch between different type files (eg. a .py file and .qml file) I have to change the build system from QML to Automatic and vice versa. What can I do so that sublime automatically recognizes a .qml file and selects the appropriate build-system when Automatic is selected? (which for my .qml files should be the QML.sublime-build that I created)

Here is my build system for qml:
(in the file "QML.sublime-build")

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "qmlscene.exe $file_name"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and [reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) for build systems contain all the information you need. Specifically to your situation, you need a `"selector"` option:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["qmlscene.exe", "$file_name"],
    "selector": "source.qml"
}
```

You can now select `Automatic` in the Build Systems menu, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will build QML files with this system, and Python files with the Python build system.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/skozlovf/Sublime-QML) is a nice sublime-package for QML. This has syntax highlighting for QML and some QML snippets and more importantly, automatic build system for QML. [Here](https://github.com/DamnWidget/SublimePySide) is one more. Though I did not use the latter, but it says it has even more features!